# VueJS Event Handler for Changing CSS

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am trying to make an input where it changes background with VueJS. I want to show only the url of the background, and not the whole CSS. The CSS I am trying to get is:

```
linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('--BACKGROUND LINK--') no-repeat center center fixed
```

The JS is:

```
function css_variable_watcher(name, prefix = "", suffix = "") {
    return {
        immediate: true,
        handler(new_value, old_value) {
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty(name, prefix + new_value + suffix);
        },
    };
}

var vue = new Vue ({

   el: "body",

   data: {

      background: "--BACKGROUND LINK--",
   
   },

   watch: {

      background: css-variable-watcher("linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(","--BACKGROUND LINK--",") no-repeat center center fixed"),

   },

});
```

The CSS variable is `background: var(--background);`

Answer (score 0):

Found it! No need for CSS

```
var vue = new Vue ({

   el: "#body",

   data: {

      background: "--BACKGROUND LINK--",
   
   },

   watch: {
        background: {
            immediate: true,
            handler(new_background, old_background) {
                document.getElementById("body").style.background = "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(" + new_background + ") no-repeat center center fixed";
            },
        },
    },

});
```